# If $A\ge0$ and $B\le 0$, are the eigenvalues of $AB$ non-positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, and $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is symmetric negative semi-definite.

How to prove the eigenvalue of $AB$ is either zero or negative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$-B$ is again nonnegative definite.

So it suffices to show the eigenvalues of $AB$ are nonnegative for $A, B$ nonnegative definite. We know the eigenvalues of $AB$ are the same as that of $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$, where $A^{1/2}$ is the unique square root of $A$. But $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ is nonnegative definite....

Comment: $\lambda I-AB=\lambda A^{1/2}A^{-1/2}-A^{1/2}A^{1/2}B=A^{1/2}(\lambda I-A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})A^{-1/2}$, so $|\lambda I-AB|=|A^{1/2}(\lambda I-A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})A^{-1/2}|=|(\lambda I-A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})|$

Comment: I'm sorry, the above proof is only correct for invertible matrix $A$, but for semi-definite (singular) $A$, we would not have $A^{1/2}A^{-1/2}=I$. Then can we still say $AB$ and $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ have the same eigenvalues? How to prove then?

Comment: For any square matrices $XY$, its spectrum coincides with that of $YX$. You may first assume $X$ is invertible, otherwise use an $\epsilon$ argument.

Comment: what is $\epsilon$ argument? can you give me a hint?

Comment: See e.g., page 57 of Fuzhen Zhang,
Matrix Theory:
Basic Results and Techniques
Second Edition

Comment: $A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}=(A^{1/2}B^{1/2})(B^{1/2}A^{1/2})=HH^T$, where $H=A^{1/2}B^{1/2}$ and we used that $(CD)^T=D^TC^T$ and $(A^{1/2})^T=A^{1/2},\,(B^{1/2})^T=B^{1/2}$.

Comment: Sorry, a minus sign is needed. So put $-B$ instead of $B$ in the above comment.